# How to get difference between 2 querysets in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

[image: when i tried difference keyword then got an error that you can see in debugger]I have 2 fields in my models i.e.,

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    tasks_requested = models.ManyToManyField(Task, null=True, blank=True)
    tasks_accepted = models.ManyToManyField(Task, null=True, blank=True, related_name='tasks_accepted')
```

I want to get the difference of these querysets in models save method, when someone create the object from admin panel

```
task_left = self.tasks_requested.all() - self.tasks_accepted.all()
```

The above code would not work can someone suggest a right way to do so

Comment: have you used **difference** method ?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.difference

Comment: what is qs1 here       qs1.difference(qs2, qs3)

Comment: To do qs1 - qs2, you need to write qs1.difference(qs2), qs1.difference(qs2, qs3) is like doing qs1-qs2-qs3 etc... @AnkitKumar

Comment: yes i did but its showing "Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this issue by converting my querysets into sets first, then the difference method gives me desired output. Here is my code

```
qs1 = self.tasks_requested.all()
qs2 = self.tasks_accepted.all()
task_left = set(qs1).difference(set(qs2))
```